# How to define the default salesforce namespace in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces, salesforce

When calling a salesforce API, I get an object as below :

```
<getUserInfoResponse xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <result>
      <accessibilityMode>false</accessibilityMode>
      <currencySymbol>$</currencySymbol>
      <orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit>5242880</orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit>
      <orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode>USD</orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode>
      <orgDisallowHtmlAttachments>false</orgDisallowHtmlAttachments>
      <orgHasPersonAccounts>false</orgHasPersonAccounts>
      <organizationId>xxxxx</organizationId>
      <organizationMultiCurrency>false</organizationMultiCurrency>
      <organizationName>WSO2</organizationName>
      <profileId>00e90000001tKNwAAM</profileId>
      <roleId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
      <sessionSecondsValid>7200</sessionSecondsValid>
      <userDefaultCurrencyIsoCode xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
      <userEmail>xxxx@gmail.com</userEmail>
      <userFullName>UserSF SalesForce</userFullName>
      <userId>00590000002mYukAAE</userId>
      <userLanguage>en_US</userLanguage>
      <userLocale>en_US</userLocale>
      <userName>xxxx@gmail.com</userName>
      <userTimeZone>America/Los_Angeles</userTimeZone>
      <userType>Standard</userType>
      <userUiSkin>Theme3</userUiSkin>
   </result>
</getUserInfoResponse>
```

I need to extract 'userEmail' using an xpath.

Can someone please tell me the exact xpath to be used?

It gives me an error as below when try out using http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html.

*The default (no prefix) Namespace URI for XPath queries is always '' and it cannot be redefined to 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com'.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the warning in bold on the page you linked to:

> The XPath tester fully supports XML namespaces, but the declarations
>   MUST be explicit and MUST be on the root XML element. See the XPath
>   Examples section for details.

In other words, they **don't** fully support XML namespaces... only those that are declared on the outermost element. This is a lazy hack, because it means that there's lots of XML that won't work with their tool, such as your example. Your example, fortunately, can be manually tweaked to fit their restrictions without much trouble, but others can't (e.g. when different namespaces map to the same prefix in different parts of the document).

Worse, what they don't tell you up front is that they don't support declaring a default namespace at all, even on the outermost element. This makes a larger, common class of XML documents unusable with their tool.

Solution: Switch to a better tool, such as [XPath Tester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath).

P.S. If you *really* want to use FreeFormatter (why?), you could declare a prefix for the sforce namespace:

```
 xmlns:sf="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"
```

and then add the `sf` namespace prefix to every element name in your XML and in your XPath expression. You can also get rid of the

```
xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

namespace declarations since they're not used, and FreeFormatter won't like them.